# Calling an SQL function in my C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have this function created in SSMS.

This is to create the function to be used to generate Unique IDs for members of a department. The idea is to concatenate whatever is returned from this function with another value that is generated from the database.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnLeadingNumberOfZeroes](
    @Value INT, @NumberOfZeroes INT
) 
RETURNS varchar(MAX) 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnValue varchar(MAX);

    SET @ReturnValue = CONVERT(varchar(MAX), @Value);
    SET @ReturnValue = REPLICATE('0', @NumberOfZeroes - DATALENGTH(@ReturnValue)) + @ReturnValue;

    RETURN (@ReturnValue);
END
```

I wish to call this in my C# code. I have this already:

```
private void memberID(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection memberID = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=EPRAISE-PC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");              
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("dbo.ufnLeadingNumberOfZeroes", memberID))
    {
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@Value", SqlDbType.Int);
        // You can call the return value parameter anything, .e.g. "@Result".
        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@NumberOfZeroes", SqlDbType.Int);

        p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        p1.Value = deptCmbBox;

        comm.Parameters.Add(p1);
        comm.Parameters.Add(p2);

        memberID.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code please?

Comment: should make sure you close your connection after execution

Comment: This looks like a bad case of copy&paste to me: `@NumberOfZeroes` is `INT` in SQL, yet `SqlDbType.Bit` in C# and its direction is `ReturnValue`?

Comment: can you try with comm.ExecuteScalar(); instead of comm.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the function and using ExecuteScalar instead.

```
private void memberID(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create a connection
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=EPRAISE-PC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"))          
    {
        // create a command
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.ufnLeadingNumberOfZeroes(@Value, @NumberOfZeroes)", conn)

        // create parameters for the command
        SqlParameter value = new SqlParameter("@Value", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter numberOfZeroes = new SqlParameter("@NumberOfZeroes", SqlDbType.Int);

        // initialise the parameters' values
        value.Value = deptCmbBox;
        numberOfZeroes.Value = 0;

        // add the parameters to the command
        cmd.Parameters.Add(value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(numberOfZeroes);

        // open the connection
        conn.Open();

        // execute the command and retrieve the result
        string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help...I wish to call the function into my C# code and concatenate it with a value such as MM and concatenate whatever the function returns with that to get something that looks like MM01, MM02, WM03 etc

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong here.

For one, you seem to be trying to use output parameters with SQL UDFs, which is not supported. You can only use these with stored procedures.

Also, your method (which appears to be an event handler) is not actually doing anything with the result of the function it's trying to retrieve. You're also not assigning a value to `p2`, and as others have pointed out, you've got the wrong datatype (should be `int` not `bit`). The SQL UDF is expecting `@NumberOfZeroes` to have a value as it's used in the calculations. I'm not sure of the default parameter value if you don't give one, but I'm assuming it'll be `NULL`, and your function will return `NULL` if that's the case (I just tested it to make sure).

Anyway, this is my interpretation of what I think you were trying to do. Read the comments, there are several things you need to think of.

Note, I separated the work you were trying to do from the event handler method.

```
private void memberID(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value = deptCmbBox; // if this is a combobox, you'll probably need to cast its SelectedText, SelectedValue or SelectedItem property to an integer
    int numZeroes = ??; // you'll have to give this a value or it'll return NULL

    string result = GetMemberID(value, numZeroes); // you'll have to decide how to store/use the resulting string here
}

private string GetMemberID(int value, int numberOfZeroes)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=EPRAISE-PC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    SqlParameter param;
    string result;

    comm.CommandText = "SELECT dbo.ufnLeadingNumberOfZeroes(@Value, @NumberOfZeroes)";
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    comm.Connection = conn;

    // Create and add the @Value parameter
    param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@Value";
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
    param.Value = value;

    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    // Create and add the @NumberOfZeros parameter
    param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@NumberOfZeroes";
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
    param.Value = numberOfZeroes;

    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        result = comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    finally // clean up after yourself
    {
        comm.Dispose();
        conn.Dispose(); // also closes the connection just in case it's left open
    }

    return result;
}
```

I knocked this together fairly quickly, so there's probably something I left out, but it should put you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help...I wish to call the function into my C# code and concatenate it with a value such as MM and concatenate whatever the function returns with that to get something that looks like MM01, MM02, WM03 etc